# What is the formal semantics approach to predicative adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, formal-semantics

I am wondering if there is a standard treatment of expressions such as "x is ready" or "x is proud". It seems to me that something like `BE(x,ready)` or `BE-READY(x)` is not enough, given that they do not capture the intuition that the meaning of those expressions is 'x is ready for/to do something'. I have been looking for a reference in the formal semantics literature, but I can't find anything apart from discussions without formal representations.

Comment: *Ready* can be a tough-predicate or a control predicate. Thus there's no telling what the semantics of the original sentence might be. It's also why you should be wary when a cannibal asks you "Are you ready to eat?"

Comment: @Araucaria-him Yes! That sort of semantic ambiguity should be accounted for in a formal framework, right?

Comment: It is accounted for in any formal framework that notices the ambiguity. That's all the "accounting" a formal framework can do. No explanation in formal frameworks; just representation. Most of the time, predicate adjectives are not distinguished from verbs or predicate nouns, since they're all predicates. Hence `Ready (x)` is enough, just like `Kill (x, y)` means "x kills/killed y". See the [Logic Guide](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you @jlawler! Perhaps we should turn to lexical semantics for this kind of words. Hopefully there are explanations there!

Comment: @lemontree I thought they were predicative not because they were one-place or two-place predicates but because they form a predicate with BE (that is, they are not attributive). Am I wrong?

Comment: Forget what I said, I was thinking of intersectional vs non-intersectional adjectives, not predicative. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @lemontree No worries!

Comment: _Be_ is just part of the machinery; it doesn't "form a predicate", since it has no meaning. It turns out that verbs don't need auxiliaries but adjectives and nouns do, and _be_ is the one, just like it's the one the Passive and the Progressive use. It's a busy little verb, but it's lost its meaning.